# How to have links in "hot spots" in an image in html

Tags: html, weebly

For a school project we are forced to use weebly and I want to embed a timeline into my website to link to my information. I figured I would use html to do this but I don't know how. I have basic html knowledge but I don't know how I would show a picture which when clicked on in different spots took you to different links. Does anyone have any ideas for how one would do this? Thank you.

Comment: If you have basic html knowledge you would know that HTML only is a markup language, and not able to execute scripts itselve. For such things you will need something like Javascript or PHP

Comment: @Azrael actually, that's doable with CSS. Use absolute positioning to float invisible `a` blocks over the correct locations.

Answer (score 2):

If all you want to do is take an img and divide it into several links, then it sounds like what you want are HTML image-maps. You can either write them yourself (http://www.javascriptkit.com/howto/imagemap.shtml) or try to use a program to help you (http://www.image-maps.com/). If you are already familiar with HTML then you should easily be able to use them to other pages or ids within the page. Good luck!